# Chi-Square Versus Rayleigh's Test for Circular Uniformity

Tags: circular-statistics

Is a  chi-square test of goodness of fit interchangeable with a Rayleigh's test for circular uniformity if one is testing the hypotheses of a uniform distribution around a circle?

Comment: No; how could it be? A chi-square test doesn't even use the information on direction in the data other than by values appearing in the same bin.

Comment: Nick Sort of my thinking too.  But I see it referenced in a number of text books.  Although I maybe misreading, unless it (chi-square)  assumed the azimuths are in predetermined bins (e.g. 0-45, 46-90 ....).

Comment: If the data arrive coarsely binned. e.g. N, NE, E, ..., NW then testing those bins against equal frequency with chi-square is a quick and easy test. Doesn't mean that it's a version of Rayleigh.